# MVC File Import and Validation without sending file back to user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a scenario where I want the client to upload a file. I've got this working, and it pulls the file into my controller. I get the first 3 lines of the file and I send that back to the user in another object and view.

What I want to do is keep the file on the server and have the client verify that the contents were good. If the client responds back then we keep the file, and I continue processing it, if they don't like it we delete it.

The two issues I'm trying to figure out is:

1. when I send back the 3 lines of the file, I don't want to send the file with it but I dont know a good way to reference it
2. if the user doesn't respond, I want the file to be removed.

Right now it does this:

User Uploads file to HttpPostedFileBase
I use a stream reader to get the first 3 lines
I send back the 3 lines in an object

Answer (score 0):

1. Create properties in your view model to support storing both the file and the contents. Populate this and send back to the user for approval.
2. Ultimately, there is no way for you to accurately do this from a web session. You could attempt to use the Session_end, but this is extremely unreliable. You are going to have to write a batch file that assumes that if the file has been in location x for more han y, delete it.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well. The files could be 2-3 mbs so sending back is not something I want to do. The alternative I came up with is load the data into a staging table with datetime and a reference guid, then send back the 3 lines + guid in a hidden field. If they respond then I can clear it out of staging tables, if not then every night have a process that cleans it up. Not elegant at all but it might be better than sending these files back and forth.